# React: Check if JSX Element is derived from a particular class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using TypeScript, and want to check whether a `JSX.Element` instance is a sub class of another React component.

For example, if I have a `Vehicle` component, and a `Car` component that extends it, then given a `JSX.Element` created from a `Car` component, I want to know if its React component class is derived from a certain one.

e.g.

```
isDerivedFrom(jsx, Car) // Should return true
isDevivedFrom(jsx, Vehicle) // Should also return true
```

I noticed that a `JSX.Element` exposes a `type` property which tells me the name of the React component, but doesn't tell me if it's derived from a certain component.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can acomplish that using the `instanceof` operator:

```
class Vehicle {
    tires: number;

    constructor(tires: number) {
        this.tires = tires;
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    constructor() {
        super(4);
    }
}

class Cake {
    public recipe: string;
}

const aCar: Car = new Car();

console.log(aCar instanceof Car); // true
console.log(aCar instanceof Vehicle); // true
console.log(aCar instanceof Cake); // false
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work as there are no objects created to compare. The type property on a JSX.Element is not an instantiated object.